# python-telegram-bot: waiting user to respond and set expiration time if there is no respond in conversation handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How do I have the bot wait for a reply in 5 seconds? if user not entered reply in 5 second then next to another conversation.

I made a bot that collects media and saves it to a database.

1. user uploads media
2. bot will wait for 5 seconds for a reply
3. if there is not new media uploaded in 5 seconds, bot will ask the user to choose where media will be located. But if there is new media uploaded then go to step 2 again
4. after bot chooses where the media uploaded then end the conversation

I managed to use `job_queue` but failed and got this error:

```
TypeError: waiting_respond() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'update' and 'context''"
```

Here is the code:

```py
async def waiting_respond(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    if update.update_id == context.user_data["lastUpdate"]:
        return WAITING
    else:
        return CHOOSING

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    application = Application.builder().token(bot_token).build()
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[MessageHandler(filters.ALL, first_upload)],
    states={
        WAITING: [
            application.job_queue.run_once(waiting_respond(), 5)
        ],
        CHOOSING: [
            MessageHandler(
                filters.Regex("^(database sparepart|database item|galery item)$"), regular_choice
            ),
            MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^cancel$"), cancel_upload),
        ],
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^Done$"), complete_received_information)],
    )
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, here is a hint for you. Your `application.job_queue` is `None` for some reason, so that's why you can't use the `run_once` function. You might want to look into the documentation for the module you are using. Also, it would be helpful to include your import statements in your code so we can see what module/classes you are using.

Comment: after i installing optional dependencies job_queque, i still got error TypeError: waiting_respond() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'update' and 'context'. any other hint?

Comment: What module are you using? Where are you importing the `Application` class from?

Comment: i use python-telegram-bot module, importing application same module

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should pass `waiting_respond` as a callback:

`application.job_queue.run_once(waiting_respond, 5)`.

Comment: just given other AttributeError: Neither 'telegram.ext.Job' nor 'apscheduler.job.Job' has attribute 'check_update'

Comment: i have managed by manually make a database and cache to mimic conveyor handler. i dont see any documentation in conv handler to set expire time for user respond